# Find the nearest point on a segment

Tags: javascript, function, geometry, coordinates

I try to find in Javascript a way to get the nearest point coordinates on a segment from 3 informations: The segment endpoints, let's say A = [x1,y1] and B = [x2,y2], and a point C = [x,y].

[image]

How to perform this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make vectors

```
AB = (B.X-A.X, B.Y-A.Y)
AC = (C.X-A.X, C.Y-A.Y)
```

Then calculate orthogonal projection of `C` onto `AB` line:

```
AD = AB * (AB.dot.AC) / (AB.dot.AB);
```

In coordinates:

```
CF = ((B.X-A.X)*(C.X-A.X)+(B.Y-A.Y)*(C.Y-A.Y)) / ((B.X-A.X)^2+(B.Y-A.Y)^2)
D.X=A.X+(B.X-A.X)*CF
D.Y=A.Y+(B.Y-A.Y)*CF
```

Note that for cases `CF<0` or `CF>1` projection point `D` lies outside of `AB` segment, so the closest pointon segment is `A` or `B` correspondingly

Answer (score 2):

You will need the knowledge of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry

It will allow you to get several equation that you will need to solve in order to get that point. It is advanced high-school math.

In your case, you need to create equation of line from two points https://mathinsight.org/lines_algebraic_geometry_refresher

Then you need to count vector that has right angle to previous line https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html
(and then find the equation for line that goes through point `C` and has the direction of your vector)

And then you need to find the intersection of these two lines
https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-equations-intersection-of-lines/